# redirect www to non-www https with apache & .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, web

I've seen a lot of these questions being asked but I have yet to find one that works for my scenario. I have tried almost every single one of them and just can't get it to work.

Could someone explain how I can get `www.domain.com` and `www.subdomain.domain.com` to redirect to `https` without the www?

Here is what I have so far:

Currently, I have the following DNS records:

```
A         @                1.2.3.4
A         subdomain        1.2.3.4
CNAME     www              domain.com.
CNAME     www.subdomain    subdomain.domain.com.
```

I also have a virtual host file as follows below *(almost exact replica's for subdomain as well)*:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     RewriteEngine on
     ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
     RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /path/to/public_html

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/domain.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/domain.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/domain-bundle

    <Directory "/path/to/public_html">
       AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the 443 virtualhost, try adding:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Comment: It doesn't redirect. Just stays at `https://www.domain.com` and says my connection is not trusted. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @bryan if you have a cert for only `domain.com`, then you will **always** get the certificate exception, because the SSL handshake happens before the request is sent, thus you can't pre-emptively redirect before the SSL handshake.

Comment: What do you suggest I do? I don't want `www.domain.com` to come up as a domain that doesn't exist. Is the only way around it to buy ANOTHER cert for www? I mean, shouldn't it at least redirected from your rewrite condition? Seems silly that it wouldn't redirect to non-www hence having the SSL cert.

Comment: buy a cert for both www and not www

Comment: Do I have to buy both, or can I get away with just buying the WWW and having `domain.com` successfully redirect to `www.domain.com` without both certs

Comment: You can buy certs that are for both `domain.com` and `www.domain.com`.

Comment: From my experience, it's hard to come by for EV Extended Certs at a fair price, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

So this is what i've learned. `www.domain.com` is different than `domain.com`. This is includes subdomains too. Ideally, you are going to want to have an SSL certification for both of these names. If you are like me, however, I didn't really want to spend the money.

The following fix works if a user types the following into the address bar:

```
http://www.domain.com   => Will be redirected to https://domain.com
www.domain.com          => Will be redirected to https://domain.com
https://domain.com      => Will stay as is, secured with no errors.
https://www.domain.com  => This is the only thing that will give a user a notice.
                           Luckily, I don't see any user typing this into the browser.
```

I've removed the following from my DNS because I've come with terms that `www.subdomain.domain.com` isn't practical unless I spend more money on another CERT, but I'm fine with this domain failing if they use a `www`.

```
CNAME     www.subdomain    subdomain.domain.com.
```

And this is now my new `VirtualHost *:80` that I replaced with the one in my question.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks again, to Jon Lin for responding and helping me out.